# How can I redirect my passport-twitter callback on the server back to the client with user data?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Nodejs newbie here working on my first passport authentication based full stack project for learning. Forgive me if my question is not clear.

There are 2 parts of my project. 1 server side which runs on port 3000 and uses express, and 1 client side based on react-redux that runs on port 8080. My client side has the "Sign in with twitter" button which redirects the user to server side "/auth/twitter" path for authentication.

My problem is with the callback which is "/auth/twitter/callback" and is on the server. I want to use the user object (twitter name and stuff) on my client side.

I don't know how to send response with user data back to client which is on a totally different server (and thus just routing with successRedirect: '/home/ won't work)

Any hint is appreciated. Stuck on this problem since last 2 days.

---------------------Code for clarity---------------------

server.js (:3000)

```
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback',
    passportTwitter.authenticate('twitter'),
    (req, res) => {
      res.json({ name: req.user.name })
    }
  );
```

client.js

```
<a href='http://127.0.0.1:3000/signin/twitter'>Sign in with twitter</a>
```

On res.json, the name data is sent to :3000 url. I want to have my client receive this data and also the authentication cookies. res.redirect('8080') is not working since I can't (?) pass on data to a redirect.

Comment: @LeandroRodrigues added code